# Reorder ggplot2 barplot in R

Tags: r

I have `dat` which contains products' features and sentiment scores.

```
TAL = c('Samsung','Apple','LG','Sonic','Motorola','Samsung','Apple','LG','Sonic','Motorola','Samsung','Apple','LG','Sonic','Motorola','Samsung','Apple','LG','Sonic','Motorola','Samsung','Apple','LG','Sonic','Motorola','Samsung','Apple','LG','Samsung','Apple','LG','Samsung','Apple','LG','Samsung','Apple')
FEL = c('color','price','name','brand','sound','technology','general','height','width','color','price','name','brand','sound','technology','general','height','width','color','price','name','brand','sound','technology','general','height','width','color','price','name','brand','sound','technology','general','height','width')
POLAR = c(10,-5,5,-8,6,3,5,10,-5,5,-8,6,3,5,10,-5,5,-8,6,3,5,10,-5,5,-8,6,3,5,10,-5,5,-8,6,3,5,10)
dat = data.frame(TAL,FEL,POLAR)
```

And, I made a plot with ggplot2 with this code below

```
sentim <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=reorder(FEL,-POLAR), y=POLAR, fill= POLAR > 0)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", show.legend = F)+
  xlab("Feature") +
  ylab("Sentiment score") +
  facet_grid(. ~ TAL, scales = "free") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        plot.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_line(size=0.1, colour = 'grey', linetype=3),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_line(size=0.1, colour = 'grey', linetype=3),
        panel.spacing = unit(1, 'lines'),
        axis.line = element_line(size=0.6, colour = 'black'),
        axis.text = element_text(colour = 'black'),
        axis.ticks = element_line(colour = 'black'))
sentim
```

Even though I used `reorder`, I just had this picture.

[image]

Although I like the overall outfit, I want those features to be in order using somthing like `decreasing = T` and just to show Top3 products with Top4 features of the highest or lowest sentiment scores - `POLAR`

[image]

Something like a picture above, I want to order features but just to show a few of them for each product.

Comment: How would it look like? I'm not sure I understand the part with Top3 Tal and Top4 Fel.

Comment: The overlapping is simply due to the size of the display window. With a wider one I get no overlapping. As far as I know you'll have to tweak the plot substantially if you want each Brand with its own ordering. With `facet_grid` you're supposed to have shared scales.

Comment: Thank you. I should use `facet_wrap`. However, what I should do to restrict the number of features to show one my graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
dat$temp_var <- paste(dat$TAL, dat$FEL) #creates a secondary variable
library(dplyr)
#get the sum for each TAL-FEL group of POLAR and sort by decreasing order
dat=dat%>%group_by(TAL,FEL)%>%mutate(tot=sum(POLAR))%>%arrange(tot)

ggplot(dat, aes(reorder(temp_var, tot), POLAR,fill= POLAR > 0))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", show.legend = F)+
  facet_wrap(~TAL,scales="free_x")+
   scale_x_discrete(labels = setNames(as.character(dat$FEL), dat$temp_var))
```

Gives:
[image]

```
#If you want to focus on what's bad and need work you can filter out what you considering uninteresting, here if total of POLAR>5.
dat_bad=dat%>%group_by(TAL,FEL)%>%mutate(tot=sum(POLAR))%>%arrange(tot)%>%filter(tot<5)

ggplot(dat_bad, aes(reorder(temp_var, tot), POLAR,fill= POLAR > 0))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", show.legend = F)+
  facet_wrap(~TAL,scales="free_x")+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = setNames(as.character(dat$FEL), dat$temp_var))
```

Gives:
[image]

And credit to Axeman for the nice [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42112100/ggplot-facet-wrap-with-specific-order-of-variables-in-each-facet#42112502) to rename the labels.

Comment: Well, I don't why I can not get the same thing with your first graph. It's not working.. Is it right that `tot` has just same values to all? It is just sum of total POLAR rty?

Comment: @Rcoding I just reran the provided code from scratch, no issue.

Comment: `dplyt` works well though. It seems that arraged by `tot`, temp_var can order the features but it is not working because `tot` has just one single number which cannot reorder temp_var

Comment: @Rcoding there is something going bad here, You should get a dataframe  with as many rows as your original `dat` with 2 more colums, `temp_var` and `tot`. Try restarting your R session and reloading `dplyr`.

Comment: It is OK , I used `reorder(temp_var, -POLAR)` and could solve the problem. Thank you!