# ggplot facet_wrap with specific order of variables in each facet

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I would like to plot these data with ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(0)
df <- data.frame(
  var1 = rep(c("group1", "group2"), each = 3),
  var2 = rep(letters[1:3], 2),
  value = runif(6, 0, 10)
)
```

The plot should be faceted like this:

```
pl <- ggplot(df, aes(var2, value))
pl <- pl + geom_col()
pl <- pl + facet_wrap(~ var1, scales = "free")
pl
```

The order of `var2` on the x-axis should be determined by increasing order of `value`. I could achieve this doing:

```
df$temp_var <- paste(df$var1, df$var2)
pl <- ggplot(df, aes(reorder(temp_var, value), value))
pl <- pl + geom_col()
pl <- pl + facet_wrap(~ var1, scales = "free")
pl
```

However, x-axis labels should be `a`, `b` and `c`. Normally, I would convert `var2` to a factor with the factor levels having the order I want, but in that case this is probably not possible.
Anybody having any ideas how this can be done? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just set the axis labels to be different than the actual breaks with a named character vector:

```
pl + scale_x_discrete(labels = setNames(as.character(df$var2), df$temp_var))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, thanks! My real data has many different groups in `var1` with different character lengths, so that I used this instead: `scale_x_discrete(labels = setNames(as.character(df$var2), df$temp_var))`

Comment: @JonSnow Yeah that's the more general solution I suppose, have edited the answer.